# Autocomplete for generic types in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, autocomplete, effective-java

"Refer to objects by their interfaces" is a good practise, as mentioned in Effective Java.
So for example i prefer

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

over

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in my code. One annoying thing is that if i type `ArrayList<String> al = new` and then hit Ctrl+Space in Eclipse i get `ArrayList<String>()` as propostal. But if i type List al = new and then hit Ctrl+Space i will get only propostal to define anonymous inner class, but not propostals such as `new ArrayList<String>()`, what is 99% the case, or for example new `Vector<String>()`.

**Question**: Is there any way to get the subclasses as propostals for generic types?

Comment: Would it be too cheeky to suggest "Use Guava and `Lists.newArrayList()`?

Comment: of course it is good, but actually i want to get all subclasses as propostal, not only for lists.

Comment: @JonSkeet You would add a new dependency (I mean you mgiht want to add it anyway, but assume not) just to change `new ArrayList<>()` to `Lists.newArrayList()`?

Comment: To be sure, I'm not sure I would want to start _any_ Java project without Guava as a dependency already...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest simply writing the expression first and then hitting `Ctrl+2, L`. Then you can name the variable, followed by `Enter, Down, Enter`. Done.

Comment: But it looks like that fills in the variable type as `ArrayList` instead of `List` for example (so you get the same result).

Comment: @PaulBellora: You missed the key sequence, which selects the second suggestion in the list of suggested types for the variable. And that should be List, where ArrayList would be the first.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your personal style of writing such code, this is an alternative inspired by the answer of @Ben Schulz. If you typically write the assignment first like

```
al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then you can use `Ctrl+1` to start the "Create local variable" quick fix. Hitting `Tab` will now directly open the type selection where you select the `List` type.

Answer (score 2):

JDK 1.7 doesn't need to specify the generic type at the right of the equal.
Preference -> Java -> Compiler to 1.6